# Gitlab Pages : no pages:deploy after passed pages job

Tags: java, maven, gitlab, cicd, gitlab-pages

I'm making a **Java** application. I want to generate and deploy the **Javadoc** after each commit on `main`. I'm using **Maven** to generate the files.

From the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/getting_started/pages_from_scratch.html#deploy-and-view-your-website):

> When this `pages` job completes successfully, a special `pages:deploy` job appears in the pipeline view. It prepares the content of the website for the GitLab Pages daemon.

In the pipeline, the `stage` job runs successfully, but no `stages:deploy` in sight. There is no *Deploy>Pages* in the sidebar, and accessing `group.domain.com/my_username/project-slug/pages` is 404 (directly accessing a file supposed to be in `public` doesn't work either).
I also checked the job's artifact : the zip file just contains the `public` folder with the right files inside (including `index.html`).

Here is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` :

```
variables:
  MAVEN_OPTS: -Dmaven.repo.local=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.m2/repository

default:
  image: maven:3.9.6-eclipse-temurin-21
  before_script:
    - mvn -version
    - cd winform-tester/

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy
  - publish

cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/repository

build_job:
  stage: build
  script: 
    - mvn $MAVEN_OPTS compile

test_job:
  stage: test
  script: 
    - mvn $MAVEN_OPTS test
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - winform-tester/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml
    reports:
      junit:
        - winform-tester/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml

pages:
  stage: publish
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_OPTS javadoc:javadoc
  after_script:
    - mv winform-tester/target/site/apidocs public
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  only: 
    - main
```

Of course the jobs `build_job` and `test_job` are working as intended. Please tell me if you  also need the `pages` job shell or `pom.xml`.

Thanks for the help.